# SPX/VIX Implied Beta Calculation

Tags: options, equities, beta, vix, spx

In https://globalmarkets.bnpparibas.com/r/Volatility_Express_20171128.pdf?t=BG3REXwMP3NZJRN7wY5Vt&stream=true, it states that

3M VIX/SPX implied Beta = (VIX 3M IVOL*VIX 3M futures)/SPX 3M IVOL

How is the RHS derived?